# Composition and isomorphisms existence given certain transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $A,B:V\to W$ be two linear transformations, in each case prove
>
> 1. If $Ker(A)=Ker(B)$ then exists an isomorphism $T:W\to W$ such that $B=TA$.
> 2. If $Im(A)=Im(B)$ then exists an isomorphism $P:V\to V$ such that $B=AP$.
> 3. If $Nul(A)=Nul(B)$(Or equivalently $Rank(A)=Rank(B)$), then exists isomorphisms $P:V\to V$ y $T:W\to W$ such that $B=TAP$.

My thinking:
for 1. I defined $A:V\to A(B)=Im(B)$ as $Av=Bv$ and then $T:W\to W,T=I_w$ is an isomorphism (and $B=TA$). But I think I shouldn't be putting conditions on A (I mean defining anything over A), However I think that $Ker(A)=Ker(B)$ get's me that $Im(B)=Im(A)$ and this mean they have the same effect over V.

I tried the same for the other 2. Is this kind of reasoning right?